# RadBusyIndicator A web call and a DispatcherTimer locking my UI. Need cancel button Windows phone

Tags: c#, multithreading, silverlight, asynchronous, telerik

So here's the setup.

on button click

```
private void login_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
```

I make a webcall

```
 classes.WebDataAccess.Login(uname.Text, pword.Password);
```

Then start a DispatcherTimer

```
            timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(100);
            timer.Start();
```

Which it then checks if the web call returned anything on its tick

```
 void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (classes.WebDataAccess.LoginBag.propBag.Count > 1)
            {
             ...
```

This all works swimmingly. EXCEPT stupid Windows Phone certification requires you to have a cancel button. So I added a cancel button and the UI is locked... You cant click it.

I have tried putting all of this inside a delegate

I have tried putting it all inside a Dispatch.BeginInvoke thread

I tried putting `async` on the tick method.

I even tried getting rid of my rad control!

Nada, nothing... For some reason the UI is locked.

I need a quick fix

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to use a BackgroundWorker

this was the hack I came up with

```
BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWoker();

 private void login_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
             bw.DoWork += (sender3,args3) => { 
                timer.Tick += (sender2, args) => {
                    if (classes.WebDataAccess.LoginBag.propBag.Count > 1)
                    {
                    ....
```

This prevents the timer from locking the UI up.